# Ensure that all messages are consumed in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I has a consumer server in Apache-Kafka and its consuming the messages.
However in the poll loop, I have a time consuming process (db access).

So my questions are:

- How to make sure that I read all the messages in a given timeframe on the consumer?
- Do I need to increase the number of consumer clients?

Comment: How do you define "all" messages? Within a given timeframe, presumably?

Comment: yes, given a timeframe. We can suppose the volume is bigger.